# Make an instance of a class that is in an another file without creating a new variable

Tags: javascript, class, syntax, require

I have a file that contains this :

```js
// filename "Test1"
module.exports = class Test {
    constructor() {
        console.log('Instancied !');
    }
}
```

I have a second file that contains this

```
// filename "Test2"
const Test = require('./Test1');

const testInstance = new Test();
```

Is there a way to simplify this to create the class in the same line as the require? 
This doesn't works but I'm thinking that is can looks like this : `const testInstance = new (require('./Test1'));`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`require('./Test1')` returns the definition of the class. So you have the right idea, you're just missing a pair of `()`:

```js
const testInstance = new (require('./Test1'))();
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the best I can think of:

```
// Test1
class Test {
    constructor() {
        console.log('Instancied !');
    }
}

module.exports = () => new Test();

// Test2
const testInstance = require('./Test1')();
```

Does this solve your problem?

Comment: No, every instance of `Test` have to be different for me (because `Test` is just a simplified version of my problem, the class has a constructor with multiple arguments normally).

Comment: My code will generate separate instances. If you need to pass arguments, you can simply pass them.